# React get input from form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple react app where a user enters a number and it is displayed on the screen.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    state = {
        list: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
    newElementHandler = (e) => {
        let newlist = this.state.list
        newlist.push(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            list: newlist
        })
    }
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    render() {
        let showlist = this.state.list
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                {showlist.map(ele=>(
                    <div>{ele}</div>
                ))}
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <input onChange={this.newElementHandler} />
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

However, I only want the number to be displayed when clicked "Submit". Right now, it displays the number as soon as i start typing. Can someone please help modify this code so that it only updates the state on form submission and hence displays the number. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the change handler, since you want to render changes only when the form is submitted. Use a ref to get a reference to the input element inside the submit handler, retrieve the value, and call `setState`:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    state = {
        list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
    inputRef = React.createRef();
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
          list: [
            ...this.state.list,
            this.inputRef.current.value
          ]
        });
    }
    render() {
        let showlist = this.state.list
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {showlist.map(ele => (
                        <div>{ele}</div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <input ref={this.inputRef} />
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Note that since you're using React, you should not mutate the state - clone / spread state instead when updating, like I did above. (Avoid `.push`)

Comment: Thanks a lot ... :)

Comment: since you mentioned about not mutating state directly, I have another doubt. Suppose the state was a single variable (say num: 1) instead of an array, Can i write: let new_num = this.state.num in my code...or is there any other method?

Comment: Yes, primitives like numbers are fine to use/change directly. It's only non-primitives (arrays and objects, mostly) that you need to make sure not to mutate. (Primitives are immutable)

Answer (score 1):

Before my answer, please take a note that the following:

```
    let newlist = this.state.list
    newlist.push(e.target.value)
```

Is a **no-no!**
You should never mutate your state directly, but need to only modify a copy of it:

```
    const newlist = [...this.state.list];
    newlist.push(e.target.value);
```

Or:

```
const newlist = [...this.state.list, e.target.value];
```

For the answer itself, you have either options:

a. Use another state slice that holds the current value:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Employee from './Employee';
import {EmployeeProvider} from './context';
import './style.css';

class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        list: [1,2,3,4,5],
        currentValue: '',
    }
    newElementHandler = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        currentValue: e.target.value
      })
    }
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          list: [...this.state.list, this.state.currentValue],
          currentValue: ''
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        let showlist = this.state.list
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                {showlist.map(ele=>(
                    <div>{ele}</div>
                ))}
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <input value={this.state.currentValue} onChange={this.newElementHandler} />
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

b. Use Form data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Employee from './Employee';
import {EmployeeProvider} from './context';
import './style.css';

class Main extends Component {

    state = {
        list: [1,2,3,4,5],
    }
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);
        this.setState({
          list: [...this.state.list, formData.get('value')]
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        let showlist = this.state.list
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                {showlist.map(ele=>(
                    <div>{ele}</div>
                ))}
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <input name='value' />
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

c. Use refs (@CertainPerformance's answer)

Comment: Thanks...also since you mentioned about not changing state directly, I have another doubt. Suppose the state was a single variable (say num: 1) instead of an array, Can i write:   let new_num = this.state.num in my code...or is there any other method?

Comment: You can write it, and if `num` is primitive, than you can mutate `new_num` and then use it to update the state or so, but doing something like `this.state.num++` is wrong since it mutates the state object.